# How to extract words instead of characters in a list using split and for loop?

Tags: python

Here is my list

```
x = ["TEST0 321", "TEST1 123"]
```

I have tried the following

```
for line in x:
    line.split()
    print(line[-2])
```

But this returns me:

```
['TEST0', '321']
2
['TEST1', '123']
2
```

what i need is

```
['TEST0']
['TEST1']
```

Becasue I have set `[-2]` to return me the 2nd to last words, but it is returning me characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`line.split()` returns a version of the line that *has* been split, but it doesn't change the original line.

Change the line

```
line.split()
```

to

```
line = line.split()
```

Or do the entire thing at once, with

```
print(line.split()[-2])
```

Comment: That's basic assignment @Lewiz1989 First `line.split()` is evaluated (which returns a list of strings) and then saved back into the variable `line`

Answer (score 1):

You are not saving the result from split method, but to show the other way you can also use list comprehension

```
y=[i.split()[0] for i in x]
```

or by using reverse index

```
y=[i.split()[-2] for i in x]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're splitting the strings, but not saving the results then getting a specific character from each string.

```
    x = ["TEST0 321", "TEST1 123"]
                 ^            ^
```

You're getting the `2`'s from the carrot positions.

Try assigning the split to variable then printing the results:

```
    x = ["TEST0 321", "TEST1 123"]

    for line in x:
        words = line.split()
        print(words)
```

```
['TEST0', '321']
['TEST1', '123']
```

Now just get the first result.

```
    x = ["TEST0 321", "TEST1 123"]

    for line in x:
        words = line.split()
        print(words[0])
```

```
TEST0
TEST1
```